# Getting Title, Author in listbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have 2 items:

```
Title = new ObservableCollection<string>();                
Author = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

I want to put them into a `ListBox` first *Title 1* and beneath *Author 1*, then *Title 2 ...*. How can I do this with `DataBinding`, `ListBox DataTemplate`?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Foreground="Blue" Content="{Binding Title}"></Label>
            <Label Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding Author}"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: i am just curious why are you using two observablecollections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would use a `DataTemplate`.

Instead of maintaining to seperate lists for Titles and Authors, I would create an object like the following:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Author {get; set;}
}
```

And then I would create a collection of Books

```
Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
Books.Add(new Book { Title="Dragons", Author="Bob"} );
```

And finally, in the Xaml I would set the `ItemsSource` of my `ListBox` to Books and bind to the Title and Author properties like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Title}" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Author}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep those Title and Author in the same class if that is not a problem. Lets say Book class which has string Title and string Author then;

Now you have an `ObservableCollection<Book> MyBooks`

```
     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyBooks}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Foreground="Blue" Content="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                    <Label Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding Author}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
```